# ffmpeg convert RTMP stream to HLS? RED5

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

Before posting this question; I followed this post;
https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-November/018558.html I also tried to find solutions to the problem I'm having.

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -i "rtmp://domain.com:5080/stream1" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 400k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 '/home/domain/public_html/hts-streams/stream1.m3u8'
```

Okay above is the Ffmpeg command I'm trying to execute to convert my `RTMP` stream into a `.m3u8`.

However the command is failing and I'm being returned this;

> I have changed my domain to **domain.com**

```
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libcelt --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Parsing...
Parsed protocol: 0
Parsed host    : domain.com
Parsed app     : stream1
RTMP_Connect1, ... connected, handshaking
HandShake: Type Answer   : 48
HandShake: Type mismatch: client sent 3, server answered 72
RTMP_Connect1, handshake failed.
rtmp://domain.com:5080/stream1: Operation not permitted
```

The command then fails to convert the stream due to a failed handshake. What is causing this?

Comment: What do the red5 logs say?

Comment: @szatmary it doesn't produce anything in the log, is there anything wrong with the above command to cause the handshake to fail? the rtmp address works perfectly